# error 403 Forbidden

Tags: error-403

tengo un sistema en donde en el apartado de registro en mi local si me sale mi alerta de registro exitoso y lo registra en mi base de datos y se comporta correctamente no me sale ningun error en la consola .
El problema es en produccion cuando habro mi sistema de manera dependiente del servidor no me registra se queda cargando  y en la consola me sale una ruta con 403 Forbidden
y mis archivos estan configurados correctamentes en mi servidor
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: De quien es el alert? Usas CDN? Es difícil sin saber que archivo es, que errores exactos da.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.